# Kubernetes Dashboard - Exposing with Ingress-Nginx

Tags: kubernetes, debian, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i am new to the whole Kubernetes community and i am currently trying to get a dashboard exposed with Ingress-Nginx. I've tried several things but i am unnable to find a good explaination on how to expose the dashboard with Ingress. All i've got now is a Dashboard that is accessible through 'kubectl port-forward'. I also have Ingress-Nginx installed and the controller is running. How should i start to create an Ingress for the kubernetes dashboard?

Comment: Couple of questions. Are you running k8s in the cloud? Do you need ingress-nginx?

Comment: I am running k8s on my Debian 11 VM i think its called "bare-metal(?)"

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor sorry for not answering my own question. 

Thanks Nicola Ballotta. This helped me alot and i was able to complete my actual goal.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @Lilin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bare-metal environment like yours, Nginx-Ingress alone is not enough, because you are missing a load balancer which usually is automatically provided on public clouds like AWS, Google Cloud, etc.

To expose services through ingress resource in a bare metal environment, you have two options.

**NodePort**

A service with NodePort is exposed on every node of your Kubernetes cluster at a static port. To do this just edit your `kubernetes-dashboard` service (be aware that naming could change depending on how you installed Kubernetes dashboard):

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit service kubernetes-dashboard
```

and change `type: ClusterIP` to `type: NodePort`. After doing this, check again your service:

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get svc kubernetes-dashboard

NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort   10.43.120.193   <none>        443:31120/TCP   9m7s
```

If you look at PORT(S) output, you will see that a random port was exposed (in my example 31120). To access your dashboard now you only need to use:

`https://node-ip:31120`

**MetalLB**

This is a much cooler solution, because it will allow you to use services of type LoadBalancer, like if you were on a public cloud provider. This requires some basic network knowledge, but it's very easy to use and very flexible for testing environments. You can find more information on [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) website.

Here also couple of useful links to understand better the concepts I explained above.

[Nginx-Ingress - Bare-metal considerations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/)

[Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)